# Does it exists any library and or functionality that provides an API for indenting major modes?

Tags: indentation, package-repositories, libraries

I am currently maintaining a fork of a major mode and I usually get by through reusing snippets other people have written that provides indention for similar languages. However, this does lead to a lot of duplicated code and or errors, since my new code is not that far from the original.

Does Emacs provide some sort of library/package in which I can specify start/end of blocks and other rules for indention and then delegate the indention to this package/library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main part of indenting is the parsing.
There is the [Simple Minded Indentation Engine](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE.html) for this kind of stuff.

The manual also gives [an example for the indentation rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE-Indentation-Example.html#SMIE-Indentation-Example).

[octave-mode in `octave.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/8a5a1bebfa95bf50ef390e4b101f1cfe8046d565/lisp/progmodes/octave.el#L250-L337) is an example for a mode that uses SMIE